# Error in Converting Object To String

Tags: java

In my controller class m reading JSON data using ObjectMapper and after dat m storing these values in MyPojo class and now i want to print the content which is there in the POJO object. If I am doing `system.out.println(pojo);` it is showing some hexadecimal value. So what should I do to get thee content.

*This is my model class:*

```
package com.ge.health.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class JSONmodel {
    private String message;
    private String data;
    private String datetime;

    public String getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }
    public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

*This is my main class Controller class*

```
package com.ge.health.poc.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.ge.health.model.JSONmodel;

@RestController
public class JSONSendController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/messagejson",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void helloService(@RequestBody(required = false) String input) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {            
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
        JSONValidationClass validate=new JSONValidationClass();
        System.out.println("Service Says 123 - " + input);  
        boolean retValue = validate.isValidJSON(input);
        System.out.println("this is the value:"+retValue);
        JSONmodel pojodata = mapper.readValue(input, JSONmodel.class);
        System.out.println(pojodata);
        System.out.println(pojodata.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you haven't overridden `toString()` in the `JSONModel` class. What did you expect the string representation to be, and which code did you expect to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override toString() with something that tells you what you want to know:

```
public String toString() {
        return "message: " + message +
                ",\n data: " + data + 
                ",\n datetime: " + datetime;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but still getting hexadecimal value

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `System.out.println` on an instance of your object will print its `String` representation as implemented by `toString`.

If you don't override `Object#toString`, you'll be printing your object in the `[ClassName@hashCode]` notation, just as implemented in `Object`.

In this case, your issue is slightly confusing because you are de-serializing an instance of your pojo from JSON, but what you are actually printing is that instance, so as long as `toString` is not overridden, you will get "some hexadecimal value" as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override(generate) the `toString` method in `JSONmodel` class.

Like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "JSONmodel [message=" + message + ", data=" + data
            + ", datetime=" + datetime + "]";
}
```